# How much can I gauge about the domain of a differential equation without actually solving it?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Say I have the differential equation

$$y' = \frac{3t^2 - 2ty}{4 - t^2} \text{, where }y(1)=-3$$

Clearly the equation is undefined at $t = \pm2$, and a solution exists at $t = 1$. Can I conclude from this that the solution must at least be defined on the interval $(1,2)$? Or could there be singularities in the solution in this interval which aren't apparent? When I see examples of determining the interval of initial value problems, sometimes the examples solves the problem explicitly and sometimes not. I'm not sure when it is necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your differential equation is linear, so  except for  the singularities of the equation ($t = \pm 2$), you will have global existence.  The solution with your initial value $y(1)=3$ will exist on the interval $(-2,2)$.

If you had a nonlinear equation (e.g. if that was $y(t)^2$ instead of $y(t)$ on the right side), it would not be easy to tell on what interval the solution exists: it could go to $\pm\infty$ at some finite $t$ other than $\pm 2$.